# how to convert a regex to dynamic?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that allows me to find a specific text within a long text without spaces, now I would like to use it dynamically to go looking for different words, try to pass it to dynamic but I can not get it to work.

https://regex101.com/r/z7mor0/1

```
const rt = "8.469.505-k"
const ex = '/\b(\w*'+ rt +'\w*)\b/g'

const cleanT = text.replace(/ /g, "")
if( cleanT.match(new RegExp(ex, 'g')) ){
  console.log("si encontro")
}
```

Comment: Your `\w` should be `\\w`

Comment: It makes no sense for it to be a string and to use the global flag in that string

Answer (score 0):

The string should not include the global flag. It should not have the start and end of the regexp. It also should have the \ escaped

```
const ex = '\\b(\\w*'+ rt +'\\w*)\\b'
```

Also you need to make sure that rt does not have anything that will make the reg exp invalid. Like the `.` is going to match any character.

Comment: the points are necessary to be able to look for what I need, if the replacements could not find the value?

Comment: rt.replace(/\./g,'\\.')

Answer (score 0):

The issue here comes from the fact that dots have a special meaning in regular expressions. Try to define "rt" like that: "const rt = '8\.469\.505-k'". You can use ".replace()" to programmatically escape dots with an extra slash in order to handle varying values for "rt".

Comment: But would I have to convert my parameter to that format that you indicate for each one?

Comment: Yes. If you use a variable to define your regular expression, you need to sanitize it by escaping special characters before defining the regex. And the "g" for global is not necessary in "ex".